# Why does Kotlin's null safety not work properly with local variable initializers?

Tags: kotlin, language-design, kotlin-null-safety

Please look at this code:

```kotlin
fun localVarNullSafety1(){
    var number: Double? = 3.0

    val sum = 2.0 + number // does not compile (Type mismatch: inferred type is Double? but Double was expected)
}

fun localVarNullSafety1(){
    var number: Double? = null
    
    number = 3.0

    val sum = 2.0 + number // compiles fine
}
```

I think that the above code consists of semantically identical functions - local variables don't go outside the scope, and they are local to the executing thread. In my opinion there is no reason for the first function not to compile.

I think that Kotlin's smart cast should take variable initialization into account.

Do I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was discussed in [KT-13663](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13663/Smartcast-variable-declaration-from-initializer-of-different-typ), and it remains an open ticket at the time of writing.

They were considering the more general case of (Note that `T?` is a supertype of `T`):

```
 val x: Supertype = Subtype()
 var y: Supertype = Subtype()
```

and decided that in the `val` case, it doesn't make sense for `x` to have the type `Subtype` here, otherwise you could just not write the type annotation in the first place.

This could make sense for `var`s though, but if smart casts are only implemented for `var`s, then `vars` and `val`s would have inconsistent behaviour regarding their types:

```
val x: Supertype = Subtype()
var y: Supertype = Subtype()

// inconsistent:
x.someSubtypeStuff() // doesn't work, x is a Supertype
y.someSubtypeStuff() // works, y is smart casted to Subtype
```

And so they ended up not implementing smart casts for initialisation back then.

Since the ticket is still open, this feature may very well be implemented in a future version of Kotlin. It might support just `var`s, both `var`s and `val`s, or just nullable types. Let's hope for the best!