# Different results on similar code with safe call operator in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I'm new to Kotlin and these two below codes give different results.

```
fun main() {
  var name: String? = "Rajat"
  name = null
  print(name?.toLowerCase())
}
```

Output: Compilation Error (illegal access operation)

```
fun main() {
  var name: String? = null
  print(name?.toLowerCase())
}
```

Output: null

Answer (score 4):

When you do this assignment:

```
name = null
```

`name` is smart casted to `Nothing?`, which is problematic. `Nothing` is the subtype of every type, and so you become able to call any accessible extension functions of any type, according to the overload resolution rules [here](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#call-with-an-explicit-receiver).

Compare:

```
fun main() {
    var name: String? = "Denis"
    name = null
    print(name?.myExtension()) // works

    val nothing: Nothing? = null
    print(nothing?.myExtension()) // also works
}

fun Int.myExtension(): Nothing = TODO()
```

Note that allowing you to call any extension function on `Nothing` is perfectly safe - `name` is null anyway, so nothing is *actually* called.

`Char.toLowerCase` and `String.toLowerCase` happen to be two of the extension functions that are accessible, and you can call both on `name`, which is now a `Nothing?`. Therefore, the call is ambiguous.

Note that smart casts only happens in assignments, not in initialisers like `var name: String? = null`. Therefore, `name` is not smart casted to `Nothing?` in this case:

```
fun main() {
    var name: String? = null
    print(name?.toLowerCase()) // better to use lowercase(), toLowerCase is deprecated!
}
```

For the reason why, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289050/why-does-kotlins-null-safety-not-work-properly-with-local-variable-initializers/72289620#72289620).

Comment: “this is perfectly safe for the compiler to allow” — only if you consider breaking later, perfectly valid code to be ‘safe’… (Yes, it's a safe thing to do _at runtime_, but that's irrelevant if you can't even finish compiling it!)

Comment: @gidds You're saying that this is not safe because it makes `name?.toLowerCase()` ambiguous, when it should not be ambiguous in the first place? I don't think this is an issue with "the compiler allowing you to call any extension function on `Nothing`" though. Doing that is safe. Rather, it is caused by smart-casting `null` to `Nothing?`, which is a bit *too* smart :)

Comment: Yes, it's clearly the smart-cast that's the problem. Smart-casting is supposed to help by allowing you to do some things that you'd otherwise need an explicit cast for. It's _not_ supposed to harm by _requiring_ an explicit cast that you otherwise wouldn't need!

Comment: @gidds I reread my answer again and it indeed is a bit unclear what I was referring to when I was saying "this is perfectly safe for the compiler to allow". I've clarified. :)

Answer (score 2):

The actual error on your first example is

> Overload resolution ambiguity: public inline fun Char.toLowerCase(): Char defined in kotlin.text public inline fun String.toLowerCase(): String defined in kotlin.text

Looks like the Kotlin compiler is being too smart for its own good here. What's happening, is that on the second example, you are explicitly defining a variable of type `String?` and assigning it some value (`null` in this case, but that doesn't matter).

On the second example, you are defining a variable of some type, and then telling the compiler "hey, after this assignment, `name` is always `null`". So then it remembers the more-specific "`name` is `null`" instead of "`name` is `String?`".

The standard library has two methods called `toLowerCase`, one on `Char` and one on `String`. Both of them are valid matches now, and the compiler is telling you it doesn't know which one to pick. In the end that won't matter, because `name` is `null`, but the compiler apparently doesn't use that final thing to throw out the method call altogether.